# How to dispatch in .then() in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am working on project where I am stuck in this problem. The thing is, I am calling an axios API and after its success I want to update my redux state i.e. in the `.then()` chain of axios. How can I achieve that? As what I have tried by applying what I know is -> I have created a react-redux dispatch in my component. I know how to do this in normal `onClick` but in `then` method I don't know how to trigger that.

I have tried doing this:

```
 let submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Axios request 
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/login'
        axios({
           //Api details 
        })
            .then(res => {
              // Store API data in LocalStorage
            })
            .then(() => {
                LogIN(); // Here I want to change redux state //
                
                history.push('/dashboard')
            })
 
    }


--Component 
function Signin({LogIN}) {
    return (
    )

}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        LogIN: () => dispatch(login_action())
    }
}
export default connect(null , mapDispatchToProps)(Signin)
```

After doing this, I see same state with no difference

Here is redux:

```
const login_action = () => {
    return {
        type : 'LOG-IN'
    }
}

const loginLogOutReducer = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOG_IN':
            return !state
        default:
            return state
    }
}


const AllReducers = combineReducers({
    isLoggedIn : loginLogOutReducer
})
```

Comment: You got a good answer of how to do this using redux-thunk but you don't need to do that.  It should be fine to execute the request within the component and dispatch an action upon success like you are doing now.  Is that `submitForm` callback inside of the `Signin` component?  Can you post the component code where you are calling `submitForm`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `redux-thunk` and function component in react hook

**App.js**

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

<Provider store={store()}>
    <AppComponent />
</Provider>
```

**store.js**

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {initialState, rootReducer} from './reducers'

const store = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
}

export default store
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {actionTypes} from './actionTypes'

const initialState = {}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === actionTypes.STH) {
        return {
            ...state,
            sth: action.payload,
        }
    }
}

export {initialState, rootReducer}
```

**actionTypes.js**

```
export const actionTypes = {
    STH: 'STH'
}
```

**Component**

```
...
const onChange =  => {
    dispatch(actionFunc()).then(res => {
        // DO Something
    })
...
```

**action.js**

```
const actionFunc = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return axios({
           //Api details 
        }).then(res => res).catch(err => err)
    }
}
```